# can someone please fix this this termux module

Tags: python, node.js, instagram, instagram-api, termux

Hi I have been using this termux instagram bot for a very long time and it is very effective too. But suddenly a month ago this bot wouldn't open so can any one please fix this?
git clone https://github.com/sanjidtk/sbot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqGmH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlnM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cis24.jpg)

Comment: Please review [ask] - you must provide a [mre] of your code along with all pertinent debugging information *in the body of your question **as text***, not as images. Please see [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the repo and perform git clone and run again. I'm not sure if it's going back to normal. I am not good at node.js part so I can't diagnose the whole issue, you should alert that to the creator and he/she will give you the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).